# How to adapt Drag&Drop in VS Solution Explorer to correctly move in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking to enhance the Visual Studio Solution Explorer. The problem I have is the following:

> When I drag & drop a file in Solution Explorer it copies this file instead of moving it and in TFS this file is added instead of moved (rename)

Is it possible to intercept or add to the drag & drop functionality of the Visual Studio Solution Explorer so that I can call the required tf commands myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the solution is already configured for integrated source control then the drag and drop functionality pends a rename operation in VS 2010 / TFS 2010.

Comment: Thanks since moving up to VS2010 + TFS2010 this is indeed resolved.

Comment: Only within the same project. If you drag a file to a different project it will delete/add.